# Changing alpha value with python without passing color code

Tags: python

A material will have some properties as "Color":

[image]

It can be changed with the python code (rgba):

```
bpy.data.worlds["World"].node_tree.nodes["Background"].inputs[0].default_value = (1, 0.5, 0.2, 1)
```

Can I update the alpha value only somehow? And not provide the color value as well. Say we want to change the alpha value to 0.5, I would have to pass the information `(1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5)`.

I would love your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use an index:

```
bpy.data.worlds["World"].node_tree.nodes["Background"].inputs[0].default_value[3] = 0.5
```